Lucas Human Capital Model with Land
We have the following Lucas Model setup: a representative consumer:
$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty\beta^t\log(C_t)$$
Production function that uses $X$, a fixed amount of land and $H_{1,t}$, human capital:
$$C_t=X^{\alpha}H_{1,t}^{1-\alpha}$$
The production function for human capital is given by:
$$H_{t+1}=BH_{2,t}$$
And total human capital is distributed between production and human capital accumulation:
$$H_t=H_{1,t}+H_{2,t}$$
I woud like to do 2 things: (1) formulate the Bellman equation, and (2) find FOCs and Envelope Conditions.
My difficulties stem from the fact that I am accustomed to seeing physical capital $K_t$ in these problems. As it stands now, I set up my Bellman equation recursively:
$$v(H)=\max\Big\{\log(C_t)+\beta v(H')\Big\}$$
I then plugged in for $C_t$, $H'$, and $H_1$ to get my Bellman equation:
$$v(H)=\max_{H_2}\Big\{\alpha\log(X)+(1-\alpha)\log(H-H_2)+\beta v(BH_2)\Big\}$$
I am reasonably confident that this is correct, but it leads to some quirks when I look at FOCs and ECs. I do not believe we max with respect to $X$, since it's just some fixed amount of land.
Now part (2). The envelope condition just refers to the partial of the Bellman equation with respect to $H$ in this case, so that should be:
$$\frac{\partial v(H)}{\partial H} = \frac{1-\alpha}{H-H_2}=\frac{1-\alpha}{H_1}$$
The FOC is where I'm getting stuck. I need to differentiate with respect to $H'$, so:
$$0 = \beta B\frac{\partial v(H')}{\partial H'} + \frac{1-\alpha}{H_1}$$
I am not convinced this is quite right. Furthermore, I'm a bit confused as to the role of $X$ in all of these equations. I either have to ignore it as I am, or I need to integrate it into my FOCs and ECs, which doesn't seem right to me given that it's a constant (although I had considered this at first, given that it was analogous to $K$ like I've seen it in the model before).
Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Your problem is
$$
\max_{C_t} \sum_{t = 0}^\infty \ln(C_t) \text{ s.t. } \begin{cases} H_t = H_{1,t} + H_{2,t},\\
H_{t+1} = B H_{2,t},\\
C_t = X^\alpha H_{1,t}^{1-\alpha},\\
H_{2,0} \text{ fixed}
\end{cases}
$$
First, we can substitute out $C_t$, $H_{1,t}$ and $H_{2,t}$ to get:
$$
\max_{H_{2,t}} \sum_{t = 0}^\infty \ln(X^\alpha(H_t - H_{2,t})^{1-\alpha}) \text{ s.t. } \begin{cases}
H_{t+1} = B H_{2,t},\\
H_{2,t} \in [0, H_t],\\
H_{0} \text{ fixed}
\end{cases}
$$
This gives the Bellman equation:
$$
v(H_t) =\max_{H_{2,t} \in [0, H_t]}\left\{\ln(X^\alpha (H_t - H_{2,t})^{1 - \alpha}) + \beta v(B H_{2,t})\right\}
$$
Here $H_t$ is the state variable and $H_{2,t}$ is the decision variable.
The first order condition gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
&-\frac{1 - \alpha}{H_t - H_{2,t}} + \beta v'(B H_{2,t}) B = 0,\\
\leftrightarrow &\beta B v'(H_{t+1}) = \frac{1 - \alpha}{H_t - H_{2,t}}.
\end{align*}
$$
The envelope condition gives,
$$
v'(H_t) = \frac{1 - \alpha}{H_t - H_{2,t}} \to v'(H_{t+1}) = \frac{1 - \alpha}{H_{t+1} - H_{2,t+1}}
$$
As such,
$$
\frac{1 - \alpha}{H_t - H_{2,t}} = \beta B \frac{1 - \alpha}{H_{t+1}- H_{2,t+1}}
$$
So,
$$
\begin{align*}
&H_{t+1} - H_{2,t+1} = \beta B (H_t - H_{2,t}),\\
\leftrightarrow &B H_{2,t} - H_{2,t+1} = \beta B (B H_{2,t-1} - H_{2,t}),\\
\leftrightarrow &H_{2,t+1} = (1 + \beta) B H_{2,t} - \beta B^2 H_{2,t-1}.
\end{align*}
$$
We can also express everything int terms of $H_{1,t}$ to get,
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1 - \alpha}{H_t - H_{2,t}} = \beta B \frac{1 - \alpha}{H_{t+1}- H_{2,t+1}},\\
\leftrightarrow & \frac{1 - \alpha}{H_{1,t}} = \beta B \frac{1- \alpha}{H_{1,t+1}},\\
\leftrightarrow & H_{1,t+1} = \beta B H_{1,t}.
\end{align*}
$$
